# Removing tags from XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have one XML where i want to remove some tags and need to keep the elements within it below is the sample.
sample XML:

```
<aggRes>
   <services>
      <serviceIdentifier>vStatus</serviceIdentifier>
      <body>
         <vStatusResponse>
            <Access>Y</Access>
         </vStatusResponse>
      </body>
   </services>
   <services>
      <serviceIdentifier>vRules</serviceIdentifier>
      <body>
         <vRulesResponse>
            <Access>Y</Access>
         </vRulesResponse>
      </body>
   </services>
   <services>
      <serviceIdentifier>vAppAccess</serviceIdentifier>
      <body>
         <vAppAccessResponse>
            <Access>Y</Access>
         </vAppAccessResponse>
      </body>
   </services>
</aggRes>
```

Required Output:

```
<aggRes>
   <services>
      <serviceIdentifier>vStatus</serviceIdentifier>
      <Access>Y</Access>
   </services>
   <services>
      <serviceIdentifier>vRules</serviceIdentifier>
      <Access>Y</Access>
   </services>
   <services>
      <serviceIdentifier>vAppAccess</serviceIdentifier>
      <Access>Y</Access>
   </services>
</aggRes>
```

I tried using this XSLT code:
XSLT code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
         <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="body">
      <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="vStatusResponse">
      <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its not working as expected . can someone help how to get the required XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `<xsl:apply-templates>`, not `<xsl:copy-of>`

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="body|vStatusResponse|vRulesResponse|vAppAccessResponse">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A less explicit (and therefore potentially more flexible) alternative would be

```
<xsl:template match="body|body/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
</xsl:template>
```

Output in either case:

```
<aggRes>
   <services>
      <serviceIdentifier>vStatus</serviceIdentifier>
      <Access>Y</Access>
   </services>
   <services>
      <serviceIdentifier>vRules</serviceIdentifier>
      <Access>Y</Access>
   </services>
   <services>
      <serviceIdentifier>vAppAccess</serviceIdentifier>
      <Access>Y</Access>
   </services>
</aggRes>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have more exceptions to the rule than nodes that should conform to it. Why don't you approach this from the opposite direction? Then **all** you need to to do is:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="aggRes | services | serviceIdentifier | Access">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```